# How to find the contrapositive of this statement?

Tags: logic

$if  \ \ \ \forall a \forall b \in Q, \ \ \ xy \notin Q \ then \ (a \lor b) \notin Q$

I hope I wrote that correctly. In English terms, it would be:
" If a and b are real numbers and ab is irrational, then either a or b must be irrational.

I want to prove this using the contrapositive but I am having trouble finding the contrapositive.

What would $ \lnot((a \lor b) \notin Q) $ evaluate to?

Same with $ \lnot(\forall a \forall b \in Q, \ \ \ xy \notin Q )  $

Comment: Your first line's right end should be imo $\;a\notin\Bbb Q\;\vee\;b\notin\Bbb Q\;$ , and its negation is $\;a\in\Bbb Q\;\;\wedge\;b\in\Bbb Q\;$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct statement is
$$\forall a,b\in \mathbb R.\;[ab\notin \mathbb Q \implies a\notin \mathbb Q \lor b\notin \mathbb Q] \text.$$
Its contrapositive is
$$\forall a,b\in \mathbb R.\;[\neg(a\notin \mathbb Q\lor b\notin \mathbb Q)\implies \neg(ab\notin \mathbb Q)] \text.$$
Use [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws) to rewrite $\neg(a\notin \mathbb Q\lor b\notin \mathbb Q)$ to $\neg(a\notin \mathbb Q)\land\neg (b\notin \mathbb Q)$, which is obviously equivalent to $a\in \mathbb Q\land b\in \mathbb Q$. Similarly, $\neg(ab\notin \mathbb Q)$ is equivalent to $ab\in \mathbb Q$, hence the full statement is
$$ \forall a,b\in \mathbb R.\;[a\in \mathbb Q\land b\in \mathbb Q \implies ab \in \mathbb Q] \text.$$

Answer (score 1):

Your first line's right end should be imo $\;a\notin\Bbb Q\;\vee\;b\notin\Bbb Q\;$ , and it's negation is $\;a\in\Bbb Q\;\;\wedge\;b\in\Bbb Q\;$

So that we must show

$$\left(a\in\Bbb Q\;\;\wedge\;b\in\Bbb Q\right)\implies\;ab\in\Bbb Q$$

which is trivial if you know $\;\Bbb Q\;$ is a field, or if you know at least that the rationals are closed under product.